# How to find indices of a vector given another vector in Thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have two thrust device vectors, let's say *a* and *b*. I would like to find the indices of vector *a* where it is smaller/greater than the pair-wise component of vector *b* ($a_{ij}>b_{ij}$).

I found the following links on how to do it with a scalar:

- [Equivalent of Matlab's find command in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118328/equivalent-of-matlabs-find-command-in-cuda)
- [Detect values greater than threshold in an array and store result in a binary(1/0) array using thrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386959/detect-values-greater-than-threshold-in-an-array-and-store-result-in-a-binary1)
- [Find the indices and values that larger than a threshold in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847049/find-the-indices-and-values-that-larger-than-a-threshold-in-cuda)

My main problem is that transform only takes one vector as input while as for the other approach, I am not sure how to do a pair-wise comparison.

Example:
*a* = {1,3,5,6,9} and *b* = {2,1,4,7,8}. I am looking for indices where *a*_ij >*b*_ij.

Therefore, the output should be {1,2,4} with 0-indexed as *a* is larger at these places than the pair-wise component of *b*.

Comment: I included a short example. I am looking at the transform variant now.

Comment: A old for-loop would do the job: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i != a.size(); ++i) { if (a[i] > b[i]) res.push_back(i); } return res;`.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, both of my vectors are on the device memory so I would like to make use of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is at least partially a stream-compaction problem.  Thrust provides algorithms for stream compaction such as `copy_if`.

Thrust does have a `transform` [variant](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations_gacca2dd17ae9de2f7bcbb8da6d6f6fce4.html#gacca2dd17ae9de2f7bcbb8da6d6f6fce4) that accepts two vectors as input.  You can also do something similar with `zip_iterator` as input to any thrust algorithm.

I think the most compact method will be to use `copy_if` with both a zip iterator and a counting iterator.  There is a `copy_if` [variant](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction_gac1155c0eddf9d5145776bd454732415b.html#gac1155c0eddf9d5145776bd454732415b) that accepts a stencil array, and that works well for our purpose here.

Here is an example:

```
# cat t61.cu
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>


using mt = int;  // data type
using it = size_t; // index type

struct my_functor
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T t) { return (thrust::get<0>(t) > thrust::get<1>(t));}
};

int main(){

  mt a[] = {1,3,5,6,9};
  mt b[] = {2,1,4,7,8};
  it len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> da(a, a+len);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> db(b, b+len);
  thrust::device_vector<it> dr(len);
  auto my_idx = thrust::counting_iterator<it>(0);
  auto my_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(da.begin(), db.begin()));
  it lr = thrust::copy_if(my_idx, my_idx+len, my_zip, dr.begin(), my_functor()) - dr.begin();
  thrust::host_vector<it> hr = dr;
  thrust::copy_n(hr.begin(), lr, std::ostream_iterator<it>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
# nvcc -o t61 t61.cu
# compute-sanitizer ./t61
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
1,2,4,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand the main flow of your solution. However, I can't see why do you use size_t len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) instead of sizeof(a).? Also what is the purpose of - dr.begin();? Copy_if should copy the elements to the output vector, dr.

Comment: the length I need (`len`) is the *number of elements* in the array.  `sizeof(a)` gives the number of *bytes*.  So divide the total number of bytes, by the bytes per element, and you get the number of elements in the array.  That is mostly what I need for thrust usage.  Thrust algorithms refer to data mostly by *iterators*, not by the name of a vector.  I'm not aware of any situation where it would be correct to pass `dr`, i.e. the name of a vector, to thrust.  `dr.begin()` is an iterator that refers to the first element of `dr`, the same syntax as `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!